# Managing path strings stored in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql-update, full-text-search

I'm doing a little web-based file explorer on JS + PHP + MySQL.

I chose to have two tables: one with folder pathes and second one with folder IDs from first table plus file names. So it looks like this:

Folders table:

```
|------------------------------------|
|id    |relative_path|status|owner_id|
|------------------------------------|
|1     |me           |1     |333     |
|2     |me/you       |1     |333     |
|3     |me/you/us    |1     |333     |
|------------------------------------|
```

Files table:

```
|---------------------------------------------------------|
|id    |folder_id|file_name|status|realpath               |
|---------------------------------------------------------|
|1     |1        |file1    |1     |/datetime_rand/file1   |
|2     |2        |file2    |1     |/datetime_rand/file2   |
|3     |3        |file77   |1     |/datetime_rand/file77  |
|---------------------------------------------------------|
```

If a user needs to delete a folder then all subfolders and files in those needs to be also removed obviously (I change status from 1 to 0 to mark file record as deleted).

So far I have figured out how to "delete" folder and all files in it without going recrusive:

```
UPDATE folders d 
LEFT JOIN files f ON d.id = f.folder_id 
SET d.status = 0 AND f.status = 0 
WHERE d.id = ?
```

I get only `folder.id` (`d.id`) to delete as an incoming parameter

What is the most efficient way to delete all subfolders? Can I do all in single query? Is there any way I can avoid full text seach, or that is not going to be slow?

Comment: You have two `status` columns.

Comment: @TheImpaler one `status` for folder and another one for file. All files can be deteled (`file.status=0`) but emtpy forlder still exists (`folder.status=1`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE folders fo 
INNER JOIN files fi ON fo.id = fi.folder_id 
SET fo.status = 0, 
    fi.status = 0 
WHERE fo.relative_path LIKE CONCAT( @folder_to_delete, '%' )
```

Comment: I get only `folder.id` to delete as an incoming parameter

Comment: If so join a subquery which will define the folder name by the id and use it in the condition.

Comment: `UPDATE folders fo INNER JOIN files fi ON fo.id = fi.folder_id SET fo.status = 0, fi.status = 0 WHERE d.id = @folder_id AND fo.relative_path LIKE CONCAT( fo.relative_path, '%' )` ?

Comment: @user164863 NO!!! `UPDATE folders fo INNER JOIN files fi ON fo.id = fi.folder_id INNER JOIN (subquery) ON (condition) SET ...`

Comment: `UPDATE folders fo INNER JOIN files fi ON fo.id = fi.folder_id INNER JOIN folders fo2 ON fo2.relative_path LIKE CONCAT( fo.relative_path, '%' ) SET fo.status = 0, 
fi.status = 0 WHERE d.id = @folder_id` ?

Comment: Would you like to post your full answer?